# how to redirect to the other page when the user answers "no"

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Selected answer is the variable holding options Yes and No, so when the user selects
No on radio button it must exit and load the other page

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Evaluation answer)
        {
        using (QuestionMangerDBDataContext data = new QuestionMangerDBDataContext())
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                var selectedAnswer = answer.selectedAnwser;
                var qId = answer.questionId;

                 // Save the data 
                QuestionMangerDATA.questionManagerAnswer tmpQAA = new QuestionMangerDATA.questionManagerAnswer();
                tmpQAA.QuestionID = qId;
                tmpQAA.QuestionAnswerID = int.Parse(selectedAnswer);
                tmpQAA.UserId = 4;
                tmpQAA.AnswerValue = "WHAT IS THIS?!";
                if (selectedAnswer == "NO")
                {
                    tmpQAA.QuestionID = qId;
                }

                data.questionManagerAnswers.InsertOnSubmit(tmpQAA);
                data.SubmitChanges();

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, strange sample, as your `ActionResult`... doesn't return anything now.

You can use an if else for redirection, which can be expressed, for example, as

```
return selectedAnswer == "NO" 
          ? RedirectToAction("someAction")
          : RedirectToAction("someOtherAction")
```

or if you don't wanna execute a part of code if `selectedAnswer == "NO"`

```
if (selectedAnswer=="No") 
   return RedirectToAction("someAction");

//this part won't be executed if selectedanswer == "No"
data.questionManagerAnswers.InsertOnSubmit(tmpQAA);
data.SubmitChanges();
return RedirectToAction("someOtherAction");
```